# Grid in footer wont fit mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, css-grid

I have a footer to my website which is set to the sticky position.

It contains the following code

```css
.footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.footer-buttons {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer class="footer">
  <div id="footer-controls" class="" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <button type="reset" class="footer-buttons btn btn-danger btn-lg" form="user-control-form">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-back-to-top">Return To Top</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <button type="button" class="footer-buttons btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="onSave()">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer-banner" class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: green; display: none;">
    SAVED!
  </div>
</footer>
```

My site looks correct when working within a laptops dimensions like so

[image: Footer spread across the container equally]

But when I resize to a mobile dimensions the footer stacks like below instead of maintaining the layout from before.
[image: site after resize]

How will I be able to make it so that my footers layout stays the same across various viewports and viewsizes

Answer (score 1):

Use `.flex-nowrap` on the parent.

```css
.footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.footer-buttons {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer class="footer">
  <div id="footer-controls" class="" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-5">
        <button type="reset" class="footer-buttons btn btn-danger btn-lg" form="user-control-form">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 text-center">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-back-to-top">Return To Top</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-5">
        <button type="button" class="footer-buttons btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="onSave()">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer-banner" class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: green; display: none;">
    SAVED!
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have just added the flex-nowrap class and this has made just the cancel button show and fit across the screen on smaller pages like so:
https://snipboard.io/4WarSt.jpg

Not sure what could fit all 3 columns

Comment: @HeavyClicker Copy over the entire HTML that's in my solution and it should work fine for you. What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 5 & I have copied the entire HTML into my project and it has changed the buttons to look how they do on the snip link above